# Buffer & process incoming data, split by newline

Tags: c++

I just found a parsing bug in some of my code:

```
while(some_condition){
    char buf[1536] = {};
    len = BIO_read(web, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(len > 0){
        process(new std::string(buf));
    }
}
```

The incoming data is json, and the problem is that I expected the incoming data to de delivered as described below:

```
{json packet 1}\n
{json packet 2}\n{json packet 3}\n
{json packet 4}\n
```

which it normally is. But I just noticed that I sometimes also can get data in the form:

```
{json pack
et 1}\n
{json packet 2}
\n{json packet 3}\n
{json packet 4}\n
```

EDIT: the newline is never on 2 different rows (had '\' and 'n' split in my example which was wrong)

which of course makes the json parser inside the process function fail when it gets incomplete json data.

So I need to buffer the incoming data some way, parse for the newline and if found send that "complete json package" to the process function and remove the processed data from the buffer.

Suggestions about how do I do that in a fast & efficient way?

### EDIT:

No replies describing any specific solution, so guess I didn't explain the problem good enough (you normally figure out clever "easy" solutions to problems which can look complex to me)

My version below seems to be working like I want, so my follow up question is if you see any possible speed improvements, or have ideas about any other way to do it which I could benchmark and and compare with this. There is no "fast enough" in this case, the faster the better.

..Or if you spot any possible bugs?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//this is just for simulating incoming data
int dataSimulator(char* buf){
    static unsigned char call_no = 0;
    call_no++;
    switch (call_no){
    case 1:
        memcpy(buf, "111\n", 4);
        return 4;
        break;
    case 2:
        memcpy(buf, "222\n33", 6);
        return 6;
        break;
    case 3:
        memcpy(buf, "3\n444\n", 6);
        return 6;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        memcpy(buf, "5", 1);
        return 1;
        break;
    case 7:
        memcpy(buf, "\n", 1);
        return 1;
        break;
    case 8:
        memcpy(buf, "666\n777\n888\n", 12);
        return 12;
        break;

    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buff[100] = {};
    int buff_offset = 0;
    int end;
    int start;

    while (1){

        buff_offset = strlen(buff);
        int len = dataSimulator(&buff[buff_offset]);

        if (len > 0)    {

            buff[buff_offset + len] = 0;

            end = 0;
            start = 0;

            while (buff[end]){
                if (buff[end] == '\n'){
                    //end of packet found
                    std::string packet(&buff[start], end - start);
                    std::cout << "packet: " << packet << " received" <<std::endl;
                    //mark old start as processed
                    buff[start] = 0;
                    start = end + 1;
                }
                end++;
            }
            if (start != end){
                //data left in buffer, move remaining stuff to the beginning
                memmove(buff, &buff[start], end - start);
                //make sure it's null terminated
                buff[end - start] = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
packet: 111 received
packet: 222 received
packet: 333 received
packet: 444 received
packet: 555 received
packet: 666 received
packet: 777 received
packet: 888 received
```

Comment: Is this C++ code built on top of OpenSSL?

Comment: *"Suggestions about how do I do that in a fast & efficient way?"* - Aren't you looking for an **effective** solution instead? You don't even know, whether that is fast enough or not, because you don't even have any code to measure the performance.

Comment: `'\n'` is a single character, are you sure you are getting the output like that?

Comment: Andrew: Yes, it is

Comment: IInspectable: I meant a faster & more efficient way than the messy ideas popping into my mind. I guess there are elegant ways to do it which are both fast & efficient.. And effective.

Comment: [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)?

Comment: The algorithm is simple: `1` Read data. `2` Parse input while there is the sequence `"\n"` in the buffer. `3` Move the trailing data to the front of the buffer. `4` Restart at `1`.

Comment: Looks like you have to distinguish between '\n' and "\n" in your parser. The algo should be whenever you encounter a '\n' if the immediate prev 2 characters are 'n' and '\' (or `substr` "\n") you are good .. else get rid of the '\n'